# Skip the open file

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below that opens each .xlsx file in a folder and calls another sub to it.  When it reaches the file that is open (unavoidable to have it open due to preceding subs), I need this to skip this file and continue.  This was modified from an online source as I don't fully comprehend using paths.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub OpenFilesVBA()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFil As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
    strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xlsx*")
    Do While strFil <> vbNullString
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)
'===========Run Objective Macro==========================================
        Call PoG_Report_Prep
'========================================================================
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Wb.Close False
        strFil = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It is hard to know exactly what you want. Do you simply want get each file in a directory and run the PoG_Report_Prep sub for each? The reason for my question is you say that you want to skip this file, but which file, and continue?

Comment: Yes to the directory question unless you know a better way.  There are about 100 files in the folder that are named in a higher sub that renames them all by a store number and variable category name, the file I wish to skip does not follow this format.

Comment: You can check the read/write status of the workbook first and if it's `readOnly` then skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a save as in a new (non-.xlsx) format and killing the original file. I used .xlsm to keep the original formatting, but .csv worked also. This comes from a report that is downloaded, so getting a new copy of the killed original isn't difficult should I need it.  The first step of my entire module is as follows:

```
'OF = Original File
Dim strFullName As String, OF As String, CurrentWB As Workbook
Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
strFullName = CurrentWB.path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & 
".xlsm"

OF = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullName, 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

'' Delete Original File
Kill OF
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the file containing this code is saved as .xlsm (rather than .xlsx), which means the file will be skipped as the code only looks for files saved as .xlsx

If the file is saved as .xlsx you could check whether the file being opened matches the filename of the current file only run the code if the names are different. See example code below. MsgBox statements for testing purposes only, remove these in the final code.

```
Sub OpenFilesVBA()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFil As String
    Dim strActiveFil As String '

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strActiveFil = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
    strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xlsx*")
    Do While strFil <> vbNullString
        MsgBox strFil
        If strFil <> strActiveFil Then
            MsgBox "run" '
            Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)
'===========Run Objective Macro==========================================
            'Call PoG_Report_Prep
'========================================================================
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            Wb.Close False
            strFil = Dir
        Else
            MsgBox "not run"
            strFil = Dir
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The file is downloaded as an .xlsx and then the macro is run.  Should the first step in the total process be to save it as a different file type so it is overlooked?

Comment: That is definitely a work around worth considering, however I updated my answer to work with the fact the file is saved as .xlsx.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I tried both suggested solutions, but was still getting the unwanted prompt for re-opening the current file.

Comment: I just realized I left a hard coded filename in my answer (which I used for testing), just updated it with "strFil <> strActiveFil", but it sounds like you found something that works!

Comment: Thanks for circling back.  If I have to do this again in the future, I'll give yours another shot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. As long as the file that contains this code is saved as *.xlsm

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenFilesVBA()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFil As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fil As Object
    Dim fldr As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)

    For Each fil In fldr.Files
        If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fil.Path)) = "xlsx" Then
            Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(fil.Path)
'===========Run Objective Macro==========================================
            Call PoG_Report_Prep
'========================================================================
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            Wb.Close False
            Set Wb = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    Set fil = Nothing
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the workbook first:

```
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)
If Not Wb.ReadOnly Then '// workbook is readonly
    PoG_Report_Prep
    Wb.Save
End If

Wb.Close
Set Wb = Nothing
```

If the `ReadOnly` status after opening is `True` then we can probably assume that the workbook was already open elsewhere before you opened it in code.

It's a bit dirty, but would work for your purpose.

Comment: I think you intended to replace the entire code with yours?  That is what I did and it is only checking the open file.  I'm not sure where exactly to insert your code into mine?

Comment: Nope. Just showing you how to check if the workbook is read only or not. It’s up to you how you want to put that into your existing code :)

Comment: I implemented it as I thought it fit, but I still get the "do you want to reopen" message and now an error
 'Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)
            If Not Wb.ReadOnly Then
                Call PoG_Report_Prep
                Wb.Save
            
            End If
        Wb.Close
        Set Wb = Nothing
        strFil = Dir